# How to retreive/set wordpress page html?

Tags: wp-api

Please bare with me , I come from joomla world and we have a method

```
getBody()
```

https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JResponse::getBody

and

```
setBody();
```

https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JResponse::setBody

that retrieves/sets the entire page html. Is there an equivalent to these methods in WordPress?

Comment: Are you building a WordPress theme?

Comment: @YoavKadosh no , I am trying to convert my joomla compression plugin to wp and all I need is the page body and page id, id I have but the whole body is what I need

Comment: So you are trying to get the contents of a page by the page's id?